# How can I fill a QComboBox?

Tags: python, mysql, qcombobox

Inside my GUI-Demo (`qtpy` and `QtCreator`) there's a `QComboBox` connected to a `QPushButton`.

Pressing the button opens my database and copies the data to my dataframe (`pandas`).

Afterwards, I am trying to pass the unique data from one of my columns into a list—which is added to my `ComboBox`.

Printing my dataframe in between tells me that it's filled correctly and I tried these lines of code in a few other places inside my program. But in this case it won't work and Python returns an error: `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`:

```
def pushTheButton(self):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    try:
        db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "testuser", "test123", "database_test")
        cursor = db_load.cursor()
        sql_query = "SELECT * FROM database_favorites_db"
        cursor.execute(sql_query)
        db.commit()
        df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, db)

    except:
        db.rollback()

    db.close()


    list_unique = df.description.unique()
    self.ui.cBoxFavorites.addItems(listing_unique)
```

Why is this error being returned and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why do cursor.execute and pandas.read_sql of the same query?? Why the commit?

Comment: Well, I'm new to python and that's what I found online. By the way I already correctect the line 'cursor = db_load.cursor()'.

Comment: I also used this code in another part of my little programm and it succeeded to fill other ComboBoxes. So I guess it might be bad coding, but could it be the source of my problem?